# HTTP ERROR 401 on accessing Azure app service staging slot URL

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, staging

I deploy the package first on the staging slot, run the tests then swap the slot. I can open the production slot URL but when I try to open the staging slot URL it gives me an error. Though the setting is the same in both environments. I tried to remove and add the staging slot again but it didn't resolve the issue.

[Page error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bw6C.png)

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your issue on my side, please try to create a new App Service and slot to have a try. According to the 401 error, you are not authorized to access the slot, navigate to the `Authentication` in the blade of the slot in the portal, make sure there is no authentication way configured.

[image]